# How to set column in table not editable

Tags: jvx

Can I make one or more columns in an `UITable` not editable but still visible, while all other Columns remain editable?

The `setEditable(false)` method of `UITable` works for the whole table, not for just a single column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UITable` is only one element. If you use an `UIEditor` the column should also be disabled. The model will handle everything:

```
dataBook.getRowDefinition().getColumnDefinition("COLUMN_NAME").setReadOnly(true);
```

The model notifies all editors and cells in a table. So above method call is enough to change the model and all UI controls will be correct automatically.